# minikube start failure workaround clears any parameters passed to kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubeadm

Here are the versions I'm using

Docker-ce

```
Client:
 Version:           17.06.1-ce

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          17.06.1-ce
```

minikube:

```
kubectl
```

Kubectl:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Kubeadm:

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

VirtualBox:

```
Version 5.2.18 r124319 (Qt5.6.2)
```

I happen to need to specify the following:

```
kubeadm reset
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

However when I then start minikube it always fails with the following:

```
kubeconfig file "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" exists already but has got the wrong CA cert
```

The workaround I've been able to find is to delete all `.conf` files in `/etc/kubernetes`

```
  cd /etc/kubernetes/
  sudo rm *.conf
  cd
  sudo minikube delete # may also need rm -rf ~/.minikube
  sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

However new config files are generated and so are the .yaml files under `/etc/kubernetes/manifest' thus erasing all additional attributes of the configuration

Up to that point doing `kubeadm config view` would show the kube init `pod-network-cidr` parmameter but not after deleting the `.conf` files and starting minikube again

First:
Is this `...wrong CA cert` error a bug with minikube?

Is there an alternate workaround that would maintain the extra parameters passed during `kubeadm init`?

I've also tried to pass the following 3 attributes that get cleared from the `kube-controller-manager.yaml` file as `extra-config` parameters on the `minikube start` command

The three missing attributes associated with `--pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16` that I've been able to ascertain are:

```
 --allocate-node-cidrs=true
 --cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
 --node-cidr-mask-size=24
```

My mikikube start command looks like this:

```
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none --extra-config=controller-manager.allocate-node-cidrs=true, controller-manager.cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16, controller-manager.node-cidr-mask-size=24
```

But I get further error when trying this

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using minikube with kubeadm? kubeadm is generally used to setup your regular k8s cluster. Not minkube.

Comment: I'm a newby to `kubernetes` and I'm mainly following steps contained in a set of instructions.
Where I have seen example of `kubeadm` used was with `init` to set one node as master and any other node would use `join` to setup as a workload node
So from hereon I will refrain from ever using `kubeadm` on `minikube`
Sorry about this

Answer (score 2):

- You generally use minikube to setup a mini kubernetes cluster of its own. Generally on your local machine.
- You generally use kubeadm to setup a full blown cluster of its own.
- You don't generally use both of them together.

Hope it helps!